# Change the ID field AspNetUsers string table to Integer in Asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I created a Web project to ASP.NET MVC Web API and C # in VS2013 Update 4, changed the connection string to SQL Server 2008 R2 and after having created the database with "Asp.Net Identity" added several extra columns the table AspNetUsers.

But I have failed to change the data type of the id field for the table AspNetUsers. By default this is set to String but I would like to change it to an integer. Is anyone experienced this? Regards!

Comment: I believe you can find the anwser here http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

Comment: In this case use MVC with Update 3. I'm using Update 4, I'll use it as a guide and see what I can get.